# Sendmail two-way SMTP integration

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

[image: integration diagram]

I have a special purpoice module (`Processing module` in the diagram), which accepts email via SMTP, processes it and then sends it out via SMTP. I need to configure `Sendmail` MTA so that every new email is routed to the `Processing module`, and every mail, accepted from `Processing module` is routed for delivery.

I cannot deliver strait from `Processing module`, only back to `Sendmail`. In fact I do not really know, what delivery type is used (local, SMTP or whatever), I need to keep existing delivery settings.

One of the questions is how `Sendmail` will distinguish new email and email coming from `Processing module`. One thought is to do it based on IP-addresses, another — to add a special header in `Processing module`.

To me this looks like a standard SMTP antivirus integration case, but I failed to find such guide for `Sendmail`. I'm totally new to `Sendmail`, please, share your thoughts or point me in the right direction, be that an online guide or `Sendmail` documentation.

Comment: Could you be more specific?   Have you invesigated MIMEDefang.org milter?

Comment: @AnFi Please, point out, which specifics could be helpful. `Processing module` is based on exim4. MIMEDefang seems to be a tool for writing milter filters in Perl, not helpful in my case, because `Processing Module` requires SMTP interaction.

Comment: Can't you make exim accept incoming messages and pass them to sendmail after processing?

Comment: @AnFi I don't think so, Sendmail is on the client's side, all I can do is give the client integration instructions. I presume Sendmail is doing some account checking which would have to be transferred to exim in this case.